# How we can give abcd&abcd@gmail.com in mailto in joomla article?

Tags: html, joomla

I have to give a email id ex. `abcd&abcd@gmail.com` in mail to funcion in joomla article. It is displaying well but when we click on this, it opens in outlook or any other mail other with `abcd` if just discard the character after &.

I am using Joomla 1.5 Editor JCE.

Comment: What do you mean by "...any other mail other with abcd if just discard the character after &..." ? do you mean to say that in the email application (Outlook etc.), the email id shows only "abcd" and not the part after the '&' character ?

Comment: ya it just discard after & in the email application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use in href mailto:abc%26%40abc@gmail.com give this in text abc&abc@gmail.com

Good luck!

Comment: Wait, why does your href contain `%26%40`? That's encoding for `&@` which is confusing. Could you explain please?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the & with %26, which is basically encoding it. I think you are running into an html entity issue with the & in play.

Good luck!

Comment: I have tried it. its working fine in editor but when we display this article in frontend it just shows the  abcd%26%40gmail.com